ITV children's television series about a wise owl and imaginary animal friends?
I am looking for the name of a children's television series, but unfortunately I do not have that many details about it. All I know is this:
It was about a wise owl (likely main character) with imaginary animal friends, ran on ITV at some point. I know that it is not the show New Zoo Revue (1972-1977) and that it likely originally ran outside the U. K. before 2000, not sure when it ran on ITV.
I'm sorry that I only have so little information, but thankful for any help.

Edited the question down to a single show.

Was it animated or live action?

Perhapse https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabeltjeskrant ?

Turns out this was Fabeltjeskrant. Thanks to @Decypher for finding the answer.

Answer from the comments:
The series you are looking for is 'Fabeltjeskrant '



